# Implementing Rule using OpenLayers.Filter.Function

Tags: openlayers-2, filter

I'm trying to set up a Rule using the Function Filter.
But it does not work: the lines on that layer are just black. And more importantly, the filtering function is never executed.

What is the mistake that I am making?

Here is the code.

```
var my_filter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Function(
    function(attributes) {
       console.log(attributes);
       var x=0; 
       return true;
    
    });
var ruleLow = new OpenLayers.Rule({
    filter:my_filter ,
  symbolizer: {pointRadius: 10, fillColor: "green",
               fillOpacity: 0.5, strokeColor: "green"}
  });


var my_style=new OpenLayers.Style( null,ruleLow);

var my_style_map=new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
    "temporary":my_style,
    "default":my_style,
    "select":my_style

});
this.vectors= new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
    "Vector Layer",
    {
        styleMap:my_style_map,
        renderers:this.renderer,
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to use the OpenLayers.Filter.Function! I solved the problem that I had.
I had to change to:

```
var my_filter = new OpenLayers.Filter.FeatureId({
    **type: OpenLayers.Filter.Function,**
    evaluate:function(attributes) {
       console.log(attributes);
       var x=0; 
       return true;
    
    }
});
var ruleLow = new OpenLayers.Rule({
    filter:my_filter,
  });


var my_style=new OpenLayers.Style( {pointRadius: 7, fillColor: "#FF3300",
               fillOpacity: 0.5, strokeColor: "#FF3300"},**{rules:[ruleLow]}**);

var my_style_map=new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
    "temporary":my_style,
    "default":my_style,
    "select":my_style

});
this.vectors= new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
    "Vector Layer",
    {
        styleMap: my_style_map, 
        renderers:this.renderer,
    }
);
```